# Data a expirar a partir da data de cadastro (datetime) - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

O campo do é do tipo datetime, como exibir a data para daqui 30 dias a partir da data cadastrada, exemplo:

```
<?php

// `data_cad` = '2018-03-01 01:52:00'

$instrucao = "SELECT 
                `user_id`,
                `status`,
                `user_nome`,
                `data_cad` 
              FROM 
                `usuario` 
              ORDER BY 
                `user_nome` 
                  ASC 
              LIMIT 1";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $instrucao);

$arr = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

?>
```

Se a data de cadastro é 01/03/2018 ('2018-03-01 01:52:00'), a data de expiração será 31/03/2018. Mas como contar a data fazendo com que o mysql entenda que o ano tem apenas 28 dias em fevereiro, 31 dias em março, enfim, a data precisa da data de cadastro para expirar daqui 30 dias.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi fazendo uso de DATE_ADD com INTERVAL `X` DAY

```
"SELECT DATE_ADD('2018-12-20 01:52:00', INTERVAL 30 DAY);"
```